# How can I get a closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^C \dfrac 1 k e^{-k} $?

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I am trying to get a closed form for

$$\sum_{k=1}^C \frac 1 k e^{-k} $$

Can anyone could help me?

Comment: What do you mean by solve?

Comment: I want to define it in the another form, for example, $\sum_{0}^{inf} a= \dfrac{1}{1-a}$

Comment: There's nothing special about using $e$ for integer powers, so presumably any formula for that would generalize to $\sum_{k=1}^C z^k/k$, but that arguably doesn't have a closed form. (You could express it as an integral of a rational function I suppose.)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html

Comment: @arctictern what do you mean about an integral of a rational function?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla can you be more specific?

Comment: I mean $\sum_{k=1}^C z^k/k= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{C-1} z^kdz=\int_0^1 (1-z^C)/(1-z)dz$. That is an integral of a rational function.

Comment: This is NOT about _solving_ an _equation_, but about _evaluating_ and _expression_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe you have
\begin{align}
\sum^{N-1}_{k=0} x^k = \frac{1-x^{N}}{1-x} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \sum^{N-1}_{k=0}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\sum^{N-1}_{k=0}\int^x_0 t^k\ dt =\int^x_0 \frac{1-t^{N}}{1-t}\ dt.  
\end{align}
Re-indexing leads to 
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{k=1} \frac{x^k}{k} =\int^x_0 \frac{1-t^{N}}{1-t}\ dt
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{k=1} \frac{e^{-k}}{k} =\int^{e^{-1}}_0 \frac{1-t^N}{1-t}\ dt.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You may write it as,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-1})^k}{k}-\sum_{k=c+1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-1})^k}{k}$$

Then attempt to write it in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function) $\Phi$. Using $\int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1} dx=\frac{1}{k}$,

$$=\sum_{k \geq 1} (e^{-1})(e^{-1})^{k-1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1} dx-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-1})^{c+1+k}}{{c+1+k}}$$

Some algebra, and interchanging integral gives,

$$=\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{k \geq 1} (e^{-1})(e^{-1})^{k-1}x^{k-1} dx-e^{-c-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{-1})^{k}}{{c+1+k}}$$

Recognizing the geometric series and $\Phi$, this is,

$$=e^{-1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-e^{-1}x} dx-e^{-c-1} \Phi (e^{-1},1,c+1)$$

Evaluating the integral gives,

$$=1-\log(e-1)-e^{-c-1} \Phi (e^{-1},1,c+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* confirms Ahmed S. Attaalla's answer:

$-e^{-c-1} \left(\Phi \left(\frac{1}{e},1,c+1\right)+e^{c+1} \log
   \left(\frac{e-1}{e}\right)\right)$